# Problem performing a mutations from react app

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

```
const ADD_TODO = gql`
  mutation AddTodo($type: String!) {
    addTodo(type: $type) {
      name
    }
  }
`;
const ADD_AUTHOR = gql`
  mutation AddAuthor($type: String!) {
    addAuthor(type: $type) {
      name
    }
  }
`;
```

I have the above two mutations to add data in my database. I'm capturing the name fields required in both the mutations in the bookval and the authorval variables. These variables are passed to AddBook and AddAuthor functions respectively

```
AddBook(bookval) {
    const [addBook, { data }] = useMutation(ADD_BOOK);
    addBook({ variables: { type: bookval } });
  };

  AddAuthor(authorval) {
    const [addAuthor, { data }] = useMutation(ADD_AUTHOR);
    addAuthor({ variables: { type: authorval } });
  };
```

Here are the functions that I'm calling on the form submit. But I get the error that Hooks can only be called inside a function component

```
 <form>
                <p>Book Name</p> 
                <input 
                  type='text'
                  ref={ (value) => this.book = value}
                  placeholder="enter book's name"/> 
                  <br/>
                  <p>Author Name</p>
                <input 
                  type='text'
                  ref={ (value) => this.author = value}
                  placeholder="enter author's name"/>
                  <br/>
                  <br/>
                  <button onClick={this.getValues.bind(this)}>Donate</button>
              </form>
```

this is my form

Comment: From the look i can see that you are using ` this.author` so your component is `class component` and you can use hook only inside `functional component`, can you share more of your code where you are calling `AddAuthor` and  `AddBook` may be we can help.

Comment: Shall I just convert it to a function component?

Comment: may be try using mutation component for your class component : https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v2.5/essentials/mutations/#the-mutation-component

Comment: yes it depends on requirement both will work. if possible convert to functional component. if its not possible use `mutation component`

Comment: Will the mutation component work just fine for two input fields also? (do i just need to add another input field in the mutation component?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
return (
  <Mutation mutation={ADD_BOOK}>
    {(addBook, { data }) => (        
      <Mutation mutation={ADD_AUTHOR}>
        {(addAuthor, { data }) => (
          <div>
            <form
              onSubmit={e => {
                e.preventDefault();
                addBook({ variables: { type: this.book.value } });
                addAuthor({ variables: { type: this.author.value } });
                this.book.value = "";
                this.author.value = "";
              }}
            >
              <input
                ref={node => {
                  this.book = node;
                }}
              />
              <input
                ref={node => {
                  this.author = node;
                }}
              />
              <button type="submit">Add Item</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        )}
      </Mutation>
    )}
  </Mutation>
);
```

> @note given code is just to for reference. I am assuming you need to add both thing from single form. if you need to add them separately you can just split code in to 2 forms and 2 mutation component.

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: this is fine, I want to add both the input from the single form only

Comment: from where do we import <Mutation> ?

Comment: `import { Mutation } from "react-apollo"` - please check this link as well [ https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/v2.5/essentials/mutations/#the-mutation-component ]

Comment: i have two tables named books(id,name,authorId) and author(id,name). i want to insert the data from input values into these tables. Can you guide me

Comment: sorry i do not write GQL backend so sorry, you need to write code in GQL backend server and add resolves something like that

Comment: oh ok ok. no problems